# Is it necessary to copy data from user space to the kernel before transfering it to an external device?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have a device driver which provides the implementation for *read*, *write* and and some other file operations. For transfers, say, from the host to the external device, it is recommended to copy the user space data to kernel space before transferring it out to the device because the page containing the user space data maybe swapped out during the transfer. However this seems to be a major overhead. Is there a possibility to directly transfer user space data to the device using the driver without the intermediate copy to a kernel pointer? Of course this would need the prevention of a possible swap out of the corresponding page(s). A similar question also holds for transfers from the device to user space.

Comment: you can use mmap which allows you to access kernel address in user space

Comment: Yes but in my case I need to make use of a device driver for the data transfers to the device. Transfers should not happen directly from user space.

Comment: This is what the O_DIRECT flag does in file I/O. The user buffer must be properly aligned and the kernel locks it in memory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send data to the device driver. Where the source data comes from? If it comes from a file, you can use [sendfile](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) from a user application program: it opens the file of source data (file descriptor fd1), it opens the destination driver (file descriptor fd2) and it sends the data from fd1 to fd2 calling *sendfile()*. Here is a [small article](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/sendfile_syscall.html) presenting this system call with a tool called [odd](https://github.com/stealth/odd), an enhanced version of [dd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) tool.

Comment: The data to the device driver comes from a user space application. It would be in the form of an array.